# How to reference GridFSFile with @DbRef annotation (spring data mongodb)

Tags: java, spring, gridfs, mongodb-java, dbref

i have a spring @Document `object Profile`

i would like to reference GridFSFile like it :

```
@DbRef
private GridFSFile file;
```

the file is writen into another collection type GridFS.

I always have a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when i set `profile.setFile(file);`

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:336)
at org.springframework.data.util.TypeDiscoverer.hashCode(TypeDiscoverer.java:365)
at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.hashCode(ClassTypeInformation.java:39)
at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:336)
at org.springframework.data.util.ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.hashCode(ParentTypeAwareTypeInformation.java:79)
at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:336)
```

I do not understand, if someone with an idea to reference a file I'm interested

Thanks,
Xavier

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar, and didn't find a way, so I made this workaround.

In your @Document class, put a `ObjectId` field

```
@Document
public class MyDocument {
     //...    
     private ObjectId file;
}
```

Then in your Repository, add custom method to link file to this MyDocument, following [advices from Oliver Gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010650/2452245) and using a `GridFsTemplate`:

```
public class MyDocumentRepositoryImpl implements MyDocumentRepositoryCustom {

    public static final String MONGO_ID = "_id";


    @Autowired
    GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void linkFileToMyDoc(MyDocument myDocument, InputStream stream, String fileName) {
        GridFSFile fsFile = gridFsTemplate.store(stream, fileName);
        myDocument.setFile( (ObjectId) fsFile.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void unLinkFileToMyDoc(MyDocument myDocument)
    {
        ObjectId objectId = myDocument.getFile();

        if (null != objectId)  {
            gridFsTemplate.delete( Query.query(Criteria.where(MONGO_ID).is(objectId)) );
            myDocument.setFile(null);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you'll need to declare your `GridFsTemplate` in your JavaConf to autowire it

```
@Bean
public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
}
```